# Error cross-compiling to ARM-linux using openMP

Tags: linux, arm, openmp, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile a program using OpenMP for ARM Linux. 
When I add the -fopenmp flag to the compiling chain, I get the following error:

```
arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure where is the compiler supposed to look for this file. Using locate on libgomp.spec shows:

```
locate libgomp.spec
/home/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2014.4/lnx32/tools/gcc/lib/libgomp.spec
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/libgomp.spec
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/libgomp.spec
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/libgomp.spec
```

Should I move this file to some other path where is it expeced? Where should it be?

Comment: can you edit you Q to include the one-line call to `gcc` (or whatever your complier is) that generates this error msg? You know about `-L/path/to/lib/dir`? You probably just need to add that, but where to add it may prove problematic. Does `OpenMP` have a website with support links? Such a question may be in the FAQ. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also looking into this. Looking into the configuration options of `arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc` itself, it seems that `libgomp` was disabled using `--disable-libgomp`:

```
$ arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v
- Using built-in specs.
- COLLECT_GCC=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc
- COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.2/gnu/arm/lin/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/4.9.1/lto-wrapper
- Target: arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi
- Configured with:
  /scratch/cltang/xilinx/linux/src/gcc-4.9-2014.11/configure
  --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu
  --target=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi --enable-threads
  ...
  --disable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libatomic
  --disable-libssp --enable-poison-system-directories
- Thread model: posix
- gcc version 4.9.1 (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2014.11-30)
```

We need to get an `arm-linux-gnueabi` compiler with this configuration enabled, or cross-compile it ourselves.

**[EDIT]**

Install `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` from your distro repositories. In my case XUbuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

`libgomp` is not shown disabled when looking at its specs (`arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v`).

The following changes needed in the Makefile used from PetaLinux to generate a sample `hello.c` application. Notice the use of `-static` to avoid dynamic linkage with `libgopt` shared objects, only available in your host machine.

```
# <petalinux_project>/components/apps/hello/Makefile


ifndef PETALINUX
$(error "Error: PETALINUX environment variable not set.  Change to the root of your PetaLinux install, and source the settings.sh file")
endif

include apps.common.mk

APP = hello

# Add any other object files to this list below
APP_OBJS = hello.o

all: build install

build: $(APP)

## -> + Replaced: $(CC) with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
## -> + Added: -fopenmp -static
$(APP): $(APP_OBJS)
    arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc $(LDFLAGS) -fopenmp -static -o $@ $(APP_OBJS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    -rm -f $(APP) *.elf *.gdb *.o

.PHONY: install image

install: $(APP)
    $(TARGETINST) -d $(APP) /bin/$(APP)

## -> + Replaced: $(CC) with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
## -> + Added: -fopenmp 
%.o: %.c
    arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c $(CFLAGS)  -fopenmp -o $@ $<

help:
    @echo ""
    @echo "Quick reference for various supported build targets for $(INSTANCE)."
    @echo "----------------------------------------------------"
    @echo "  clean                  clean out build objects"
    @echo "  all                    build $(INSTANCE) and install to rootfs host copy"
    @echo "  build                  build subsystem"
    @echo "  install                install built objects to rootfs host copy"
```

For completeness, the following is the `hello.c` sample code:

```
/*
 * Placeholder PetaLinux user application.
 *
 * Replace this with your application code
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello, PetaLinux World!\n");
    printf("cmdline args:\n");
    while(argc--)
        printf("%s\n",*argv++);


#pragma omp parallel
        printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d\n",
               omp_get_thread_num(),
               omp_get_num_threads());
    return 0;
}
```

And finally, build and jtag transfer, from PetaLinux framework:

```
<petalinux_project>$ petalinux-build -v -c rootfs/hello
<petalinux_project>$ petalinux-build -x package
<petalinux_project>$ petalinux-boot --jtag --fpga --bitstream pre-built/linux/implementation/download.bit --u-boot --kernel
```

Comment: that' really nice! any idea on how to replicate this if using SDSoC?

Comment: Hi @Leos313, I am having the same issue in SDSoC. Have you figured out how to compile with OpenMP in SDSoC?